# Blackberry Application exit callback

Tags: blackberry

I would like my application to requestBackground when the user exits the application. Is there a callback for when the user exits the application so that I may requestBackground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Screens receive an **onClose()** call before they are closed. When the first screen on the stack (the first screen that is started when your application starts) closes, the application is terminated.

Override the **onClose()** method of the first screen on the UI stack in your application, and request background.